# How to monitor power consumption on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: power-management

Is there a way to monitor power consumption in watts? I have tried [PowerTOP](https://01.org/powertop/) but it measures the usage in percentages, which is not what I want.

Comment: if your server has ipmi you can try ipmitool

Comment: No ipmi by the looks of it

Comment: Depends on your processor. For some processors, package energy is available via MSR. turbostat (linux-tools-common) can read and display it.

Comment: thank you. turbostat is cool.

Answer (score 2):

You can try **Powerstat**.
It is available at `ppa:colin-king/powermanagement`

[image]

Comment: Throw in 60 watts for the light bulb you use around the computer :)

Comment: powerstat, powertop, turbostat etc. calculate wattage monitoring battery discharge. My machine is a desktop.

Comment: No, turbostat does not calculate wattage from monitoring any battery stuff. It reads energy usage directly from the processor itself. However, that doesn't include other consumption sources within a computer.